# How to make http requests with Blazor? Trying but throwing me an error

Tags: c#, http, blazor

Hey guys i have this code:

Treinos.json

```
{
  "TREINOS_SEMANA": {
    "Registros": 6,
    "DiasSemana": [
      {
        "DiaNum": "2",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "2",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DiaNum": "3",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "3",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DiaNum": "4",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "4",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DiaNum": "5",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "5",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DiaNum": "6",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "6",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DiaNum": "7",
        "DiaQtdeTreinos": 1,
        "DiaTreinos": [
          {
            "TreinoID": "32",
            "TreinoDiaSemana": "7",
            "TreinoDescricao": "INICIANTE",
            "TreinoCategoria": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ErroMsg": false
  }
}
```

Treinos.cs

```
namespace BlazorApp.Classes
{
    public partial class Treinos
    {
        public TreinosSemana TreinosSemana { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TreinosSemana
    {
        public long Registros { get; set; }

        public DiasSemana[] DiasSemana { get; set; }

        public bool ErroMsg { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DiasSemana
    {
        public long DiaNum { get; set; }

        public long DiaQtdeTreinos { get; set; }

        public DiaTreino[] DiaTreinos { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DiaTreino
    {
        public long TreinoId { get; set; }

        public long TreinoDiaSemana { get; set; }

        public string TreinoDescricao { get; set; }

        public object TreinoCategoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Home.razor

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http


@code {

    private Treinos treinos = new Treinos();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        treinos = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Treinos>("sample-data/treinos.json");
        Console.WriteLine(treinos.TreinosSemana.Registros);
    }
}
```

But this is throwing me an error:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: ﻿Unhandled exception rendering component:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at BlazorApp.Pages.Home.OnInitializedAsync () [0x0009b] in E:\Programação\Blazor\BlazorApp\Pages\Home.razor:12

> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x1f47d40 + 0x00176> in <79f1a91c13df4c50b01e437f9a5bf79e>:0

> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x2160560 + 0x000f4> in <79f1a91c13df4c50b01e437f9a5bf79e>:0

What am i doing wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: You have to [annotate your class with `JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) so that `TREINOS_SEMANA` is recognised as `TreinosSemana`. `GetJsonAsync<T>` does not magically know that these are the same. Alternatively, use a [Naming Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: So how my Class is supose to be declared? Only reading the link i didn't understood very well

Comment: The names used in your class must be able to be matched up to the names in the Json, by a combination of naming policy - e.g. "Ignore case" - and explicit mapping - "When you see TREINOS_SEMANA, match that to TreinosSemana". You can't just define names which are similiar and expect the deserializer to realize 'oh, this is what they mean, I'll use that'

Comment: Do you have an endpoint at "sample-data/treinos.json" or is that just some file sitting on your computer?